# API to get MIP label from a file residing on remote share

Tags: azure, microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection, mip-sdk

I need to read the MIP label(If it is there) from a file residing on a remote shares like SMB\DFS or NFS share. One option is to download the file locally and then read file label using MIP SDK. But considering there could be very big data files, I find this option very inefficient.

Is there a better option to read MIP labels from a very large file without downloading the complete file locally ?

Thanks,
Bishnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't. The SDK needs the entire file.